# Use VB.net and MySQL exported sql file in other computer

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm done coding in vb.net with mysql as my database. And also I'm done exporting mysql database into .sql file and done building my code into an application, but there's a problem, when im trying to run my application in other computer, my application didnt read the exported mysql database file. can anyone help me how to fix this? i've attached some few lines of my code if someone ask my code.

```
 Dim query As String
    Dim count As Integer

    sqlcon = New MySqlConnection
    sqlcon.ConnectionString =
    "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=svfmemberlistdb"

    Try
        sqlcon.Open()
        query = " SELECT * FROM svfmemberlistdb.account where username='" & txtUser.Text & "' and password='" & txtPass.Text & "' "
        sqlcmd = New MySqlCommand(query, sqlcon)
        sqlrdr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader

        count = 0

        While sqlrdr.Read
            count = count + 1
        End While

        If count = 1 Then
            Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successful")
            Me.Hide()
        ElseIf count > 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Username or Password are Duplicated")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Login Failed, Invalid Username or Password")
        End If

        sqlcon.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

this is the error message appear when i try to run my build application with it's database in other computer.

[image: error message]

Comment: can you show your code accessing to your SQL

Comment: ive attach a few lines of my code to the question. @GustiArya

Comment: also attach what the error says

Comment: ive already attached the error message. @GustiArya

Comment: try change server="localhost" into server="ipaddress where databse is installed"

Comment: same error message. how can i link my exported .sql file to my application? i think it's the solution but i dont know how to put it in code

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a8fa22d0-1f0f-4133-8238-4115b6f3fb18/read-sql-file-in-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: like using MS Access, I can use Access database with vb application without installing VS and MS Access in other computer, I want to do that too, but this time in MySQL database. how to do that?

Comment: Never ever store passwords as plain text - hash them.  Its is also a bad idea to use the root ID  from your app.  Otherwise the error is telling you whats wrong - MySQL cant find a DB by that name